# Toggling between responsive on Zurb's Foundation 5

Tags: zurb-foundation

So it's only been out for a very short while, but I was wondering if anybody had any idea to stop Foundation 5 from being responsive?

We have a theme which relies on Foundation 5, however a new client wants to use the theme, without it being responsive. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you not start by removing all media queries that act in this way? I'm not sure if they have JS that also contributes to your problem though.

Comment: It might come down to that, I was just hoping somebody had done it before and could throw some pointers instead of me going through quite a few minified files reading all the code.

Comment: Well if you do figure it out, stick it on GitHub.

Comment: For sure! To be honest we've been thinking about switching to Bootstrap any way, so it might just be a case of doing that instead.

Comment: bootstrap 2.3 or 3 will have the same responsive stacking behavior as foundation. You might consider 960 grid or something pre-responsive if you are looking for an alternative grid based layout lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the sass variables that set the breakpoints that define the media queries, just set them to extreme values so that they do not trigger. This will provide very poor ux on devices with small displays. Another solution would be to match all of the grids, so if you have a `.large-12` then add `.small-12 .large-12` for each instance.

Here are the defaults pulled from the [zurb foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/global.html):

```
$small-range: (0em, 40em);
$medium-range: (40.063em, 64em);
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em);
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em);
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em);

$screen: "only screen" !default;

$landscape: "#{$screen} and (orientation: landscape)" !default;
$portrait: "#{$screen} and (orientation: portrait)" !default;

$small-up: $screen !default;
$small-only: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)})" !default;

$medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})" !default;
$medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})" !default;

$large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})" !default;
$large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})" !default;

$xlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)})" !default;
$xlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xlarge-range)})" !default;

$xxlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)})" !default;
$xxlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xxlarge-range)})" !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the css media queries using Sass which will be quite easy i guess than using media queries with css.Simply remove or set the same numbers on all the resolutions.
thanks.